# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFConstantString' (0x10c06ffb0) to 'NSData'

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting error when trying to cast saved strings in JSON format to Data type. My code is:

```
let persistData = UserDefaults.standard
if ((persistData.object(forKey: "udchatRespones")) != nil)
{
    print("Bug")
    print(persistData.object(forKey: "udchatRespones"))
    let decoded  = persistData.object(forKey: "udchatRespones") as! Data
    chatRespones = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [ApplicationChat]
    if chatRespones.count <= 0 {
        chatRespones = EllaBusiness().chat(ctx: "1", value: "Hi")
        let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: chatRespones)
        persistData.set(encodedData, forKey: "udchatRespones")
        persistData.synchronize()
    }
}
```

When I am printing the "udchatRespones" its giving "optional()"

Comment: You can't convert a String to Data using a cast. If you want Data, store Data, not a String.

Comment: BTW - UserDefaults is not the proper place to store app data. Write your data to a file.

Comment: And you don't need `.synchronize()`. Actually you should avoid using it: the *only* time it could be useful is if the app is going to be killed just after setting the defaults (and even then, it's not always necessary).